# Entity Framework, similar but different databases - can we use inheritance between entity classes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

Our applications use a number of different databases that are managed by a third party and whose tables have pretty much the same structure all over.

Pretty much, but not quite. For instance, the `T_Article` table has an `Article_Type` field in one database (let's call it DB1) but not in the other (DB2). (For what it's worth, it takes its value from a wholly different database that the same applications also use.)

We already have an `Article` entity:

```
    public class Article
    {
        public string ArtReference { get; set; }
        public string ArtDesignation { get; set; }
        public string ArtType { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method called by the DbContext object's OnModelCreating() to define equivalences between this entity
        /// and table T_Article.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="p_etbTable">Model's Article entity</param>
        public static void CreateModel(EntityTypeBuilder<Article> p_etbTable)
        {
            // Table name
            p_etbTable.ToTable("T_Article");

            // Primary key
            p_etbTable.HasKey(t => new { t.ArtReference }).HasName("PK_ARTREF_T_ARTICLE");
            
            // Fields
            p_etbTable.Property(t => t.ArtReference).IsRequired();
            p_etbTable.Property(t => t.ArtReference).HasColumnName("Ar_Ref");
            p_etbTable.Property(t => t.ArtReference).HasColumnType("varchar(19)");
            p_etbTable.Property(t => t.ArtReference).HasMaxLength(19);
            p_etbTable.Property(t => t.ArtDesignation).HasColumnName("Ar_Desi");
            p_etbTable.Property(t => t.ArtDesignation).HasColumnType("varchar(69)");
            p_etbTable.Property(t => t.ArtDesignation).HasMaxLength(69);
            p_etbTable.Property(t => t.ArtType).HasColumnName("Ar_Type");
            p_etbTable.Property(t => t.ArtType).HasColumnType("varchar(35)");
            p_etbTable.Property(t => t.ArtType).HasMaxLength(35);
        }
```

Now, one application also needs to access DB2, in which `T_Article` has no `Ar_Type` column.

Trying to load an `Article` object from `DB2..T_Article` results in an exception (since Entity Framework doesn't find that `Ar_Type` column), so we're opting to create another class, called `LimitedArticle`, that has `ArtReference` and `ArtDesignation`, and to make `Article` derive from `LimitedArticle`.

Now `CreateModel()` described above throws an exception because `EntityTypeBuilder<Article>` can't be converted to `EntityTypeBuilder<LimitedArticle>`.

I see two ways out of this:

- Find a way to convert `EntityTypeBuilder<Article>` to `EntityTypeBuilder<LimitedArticle>`.
- Find a way to make loading some columns optional (maybe lazy loading per column? Is that even a thing?).

But I would gratefully welcome others. What can we do about this?

Comment: (By the way, the rather obvious solution to define the same fields twice in `LimitedArticle` and `Article` without a relationship between the two is currently under way to make things move along, but is considered undesirable because, y'know, redundancy.)

Comment: I'm not a fan of inheritance in case of models. No matter if they act as DB structures, DTO's or whatever. So I would create a different set of models for a different set of DBMS systems IF they differ. But first I would ask the question why they differ? Sounds odd to have an app which should run on different DBMS and have different fields on some DBMS.

Comment: A DbContext isn't a materialization of a database model. An entity isn't a model of a table. You can use the same DbContext and entities with different databases. You can use [Ignored in the Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=fluent-api%2Cwithout-nrt#included-and-excluded-properties) to ignore a property based on some configuration condition. Of course, that's a lot easier if the model and mapping code remains in its proper place, instead of getting spread around in the DTOs

Comment: BTW that's just one of the problems with putting the configuration code in `Article`. The fundamental problem is that ORMs are designed to *separate* the DTOs from mapping and storage concerns. In this case you need two different mappings, but the mapping is hard-coded into the DTO. The `Article` class shouldn't have to change every time a table or property name changes. It shouldn't have to know about database types and codepages (varchar or nvarchar? If varchar, what codepage?)

Comment: @user743414: It does sound odd, but as I mentioned the databases are managed by a third party. Maybe the best option could be to ask them to add the custom fields in all the bases. I'll have to bring it up, but I don't put much stock in it for various intra-organization reasons.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : Very interesting point about Ignored(). Of course, we would need to let `CreateModel()` know which database we are working with so it can ignore or use the columns accordingly.

Comment: @Jean-DavidLanz one more reason why mixing up DTOs with mapping and configuration code is a bad idea. Mapping is the concern of DbContext, not Article

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos (second and third comments): We-eelll, maybe I made a bad choice then. It seemed consistent to have all the information relevant to a table in the entity class. Sounds much better than having all the `CreateModel()`s in a huge `DBContext` class, but maybe we could split that code in distinct classes, one per table? Still, I'd rather avoid having one per table and database -- see my above comment about redundancy.

Comment: But an entity isn't a table. It's an application entity. The ORM (in this case EF Core) *M*aps that *O*bject to the *R*elational construct - table, view, stored procedure or raw SQL output. That's what ORM means. The same entity/object could be mapped to different tables, views or even completely different databases if you changed the mapping code. Your `Article` could be stored in SQLite, Oracle or PostgeSQL without changing the class itself, only the mapping. EF Core even maps to CosmosDB, a *non*-relational database

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234624/discussion-between-jean-david-lanz-and-panagiotis-kanavos).